# Trouble recognizing cookies

Tags: php, cookies

The code is below. I've had this problem with the most recent version of firefox. I checked the other forums and haven't found any solution. I think I'm doing something wrong maybe? As you can probably tell, I'm somewhat new to php.

Also, I know my approach is a bit unorthodox to a lot of other things in this code. However, the issue I'm looking to resolve is the if statement-test where it checks if $_COOKIE['auth'] is set. I checked my cookies and IT IS SET. I tested with some die() statements, and it is not being picked up. Any help?

```
<?php


//THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM EVIDENTLY OCCURS
if (isset($_COOKIE['auth'])){
if ($_SESSION['auth'] > 0){
    header ("Location: /members/index.php");
} else {
    setcookie ('auth', '', time() - 3600, "/", "www.domain-here.com");
}
} else {
$old_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$username = "";
$password = "";

if ($_POST['username'] != "" && $_POST['password'] != ""){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $expire = 0;
    if ($_POST['save'] == "checked"){
        $expire = time()+60*60*24*14;
    }

    //$result = db query to check if user exists

    if ($result) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            session_start();
            setcookie("auth", $sid, $expire, "/", "www.domain-here.com"); //here I am setting the cookie to allow users to stay logged on
            header ("Location: $old_url");
        } else {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['auth'] = "0";
            die(alert("Invalid username or password.", "login.php"));
        }
    } else {
        die(alert("Invalid username or password.", "login.php"));
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove all the code irrelevant to the problem and try to ask again. Session and database make no sense in cookies-related question

Comment: ^^ It's been edited. I took out most of the unrelated session/db stuff.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? It looks like you're just doing session handling, in which case I don't get why you need to store the `auth` cookie.

Comment: the goal is to store a cookie once someone logs in. thus they will remain logged in should they leave and come back in a different session.

Answer (score 0):

OK first off, you're using time()-3600 that means your cookie's less than 0? next up. you need to give it a value or else it won't set the cookie. here's the corrected code.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['auth'])){
if ($_SESSION['auth'] > 0){
    header ("Location: /admin/itemdev.php");
} else {
    setcookie ('auth', 'my value', time() + 3600, "/", "localhost");

}
}
```